# How to find invoked element without passing this

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript function called many times from many pages.

Inside this function I have to check the element which is invoked this function.

I know a method to pass 'this' with the function call. I cannot use that method. Because I am working only on a single module. 
There are many other modules using this function. So if I change the function definition it will throw error for other modules/pages.

Is there any other way to find the invoked element without passing 'this' or without changing the function definition.

Comment: can you put some sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it will throw an error? It's perfectly legal to call a javascript function without passing in all the arguments.

Passing in too many arguments is also legal, you access them with the `arguments` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You will not have to modify the `functions` signature. You can pass arguments and access them using the `arguments` variable.

Eg

```
<a href="#" onclick='foo()' id='one'>One</a>
<a href="#" onclick='foo(this)' id='two'>Two</a>
<script>
    function foo() {
    if(arguments.length==1)
    {
        alert("Called from element with id "+arguments[0].id);
    }    
    else{
        alert("No element specified")                 
    }
}
</script>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TvpMy/)